# How to change the image of a @IBAction button when there's a state change on another element (bluetooth in this case)?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a small app to connect to a bluetooth peripheral and configure it. All the bluetooth part works fine but I'm struggling to set the image associated with the @IBAction based on the connection state. If the bluetooth device is connected I want to to show an image to send and if not an image to scan.

Using the *setNeedsDisplay()* method when the central manager gets the *didDisconnectPeripheral* state change, I can change the image associated with the button but it only gets updated after the button is next touched (same as the image for the *.normal* state).

Is there a way to force a reload of the image short of writing a button programatically? Here's the code that sets the image after it's pressed:

```
    var stateImage = UIImage(named: "send")

@IBAction func btoothConf(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.setImage(stateImage, for: .normal)

    if (peripheral != nil) && (peripheral.state == .connected) {
        sendCmd(command, peripheral!, writeChar)
    } else {
        self.scan()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've managed to get the functionality I want by doing the following but it seems like a kludge.

1. Added an *@IBOutlet weak var connectionState: UIButton!* and linked it to the same button.
2. Included *self.connectionState.setImage(stateImage, for: .normal)* in the bluetooth functions that handle the state transitions. The connect and disconnect transitions define different images for the *stateImage* variable.

It works but to my mind there should be a simpler way given that I can set the image after the button is clicked (or before but only the background image).

Comment: This would be a good answer without the last paragraph. What you've described in your steps 1 and 2 is essentially how you do it.